# Search items of an anonymous model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search

I have:

```
   IEnumerable<CustomModel> model = //some joins and select here;
```

How would I do something like this?

```
   if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
        {
            return View(model.Where(m => m.Description.Contains(keyword) ||
                m.Title.Contains(keyword)).ToList());
        }

   return View(model.ToList());
```

This code doesn't work if you're wondering. What I'm trying to do is return only the items that contains the search keyword.
Here's the error:

```
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.            
   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in     
   the code. 

   Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

 Line 132:            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search_idea))
 Line 133:            {
 Line 134:                return View(model.Where(m => m.Description.Contains(search_idea) ||
 Line 135:                    m.Title.Contains(search_idea)).ToList());
 Line 136:            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The condition should be negated: `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues that I see with this code.

First, consider the fact that `keyword` here is probably case sensitive, and you should alter your code to search without consideration to case sensitivity.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
{
    return View(model.Where(m => 
        m.Description.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1 ||
        m.Title.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
    .ToList());
}

return View(model.ToList());
```

Second, make sure that `m.Description` and `m.Title` are not null since calling `null.IndexOf` or `null.Contains` will cause a `NullReferenceException`:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
{
    return View(model.Where(m => 
        (m.Description ?? "").IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1 ||
        (m.Title ?? "").IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
    .ToList());
}

return View(model.ToList());
```

Comment: Yep. Ironically, you've stated that if there is a keyword, the section that filters by that keyword should be skipped.

Comment: my bad, it was a typo when I try to type it up here. I'

Comment: In the future please provide accurate code and as much detail (such as your `NullReferenceException`) as possible up front. This will ensure you get better answers, faster.

Comment: yea i'm afraid of posting too much words and make it harder to read. I'll keep that in mind, sorry.

Comment: @user3758745 no need to apologize. Just trying to help you get a better answer, faster!